# Why doesnt setCookie function fire in this instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a setCookie function which fires correctly in more instances but doesn't seem to fire with this very specific instance.

The setCookie function works correctly within the HTML file, but fails the fire from an external app.js file even though the parent storeSelection function works fine. I've tested by placing a console.log message within setCookie and can confirm doesn't run when triggered from $('.store-select').change

```
index.html

function getCookie() {
    //cookie function
}

function setCookie() {
    //cookie function
}


function storeSelection(region) {
    setCookie("geo-location-v3", region, 365); 
});

var region = getCookie('geo-location-v3');

if (region == "") { 

   if (location == 'us') {
       region = 'us'; 
   } else  {
       region = 'au';
   }
   
   //This CORRECTLY fires storeSelection function which fires setCookie function and saves the cookie
   storeSelection(region); 

}
```

In an external javascript file I have:

```
app.js:

$('.store-select').change(function(){
    region = 'au'
    
    //This DOESNT fire setCookie function
    setCookie("geo-location-v3", region, 365); 
    
    //This CORRECTLY fires storeSelection function, but  DOESNT fire the setCookie function within storeSelection
    storeSelection(region)  
});
```

Comment: _"and can confirm doesn't run when triggered from $('.store-select').change"_ - most likely because that change callback never fired in the first place. And that, again, most likely because `$('.store-select')` did not actually find any element(s), in the moment this code actually ran.

Comment: The change callback does fire, the storeSelection function runs from the 'change' and I've tested with a console.log message.

Comment: `//This DOESNT fire setCookie function` - that makes no sense, either it finds & executes that function at this point, or you would have to get an error. Problem probably rather lies _within_ that function then.